# Notation problem

Tags: dependent-type, interactive-proofs, coq

The following problem arises when I try to define a new notation. I have a function

```
f : A -> A -> A -> A -> Type
```

Then I want special notation for the value of this function.

```
Notation " [ a b c d] " := (f a b c d).
```

The function needs 4 arguments by definition. However, Coq does not accepts this saying there are undefined references. Strangely, if I remove them (a and d specifically), so only b and c remain then it checks. I should maybe say that f is defined with an implicit argument. Even if I change it for an explicit argument the same thing occurs.
Can someone explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The right-hand side needs to be in parantheses. I.e., you want `Notation "[ a b c d ]" := (f a b c d).` in here.

Comment: I edited to what I had from the beginning in my code, exactly what you wrote and it gives the problem. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Oh, the issue is that it's seeing `d]` as a token. Notice that in my comment, I have added a space between `d` and `]`.

Comment: As cstheory is for research-level questions, this questions might be more suitable for http://proofassistants.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a space after the `d`, before the `]`.